# Factorial implementation and Lua runtime

Tags: lua

I implemented a simply factorial function in Lua and for some not to high number, 25 for example, the result is incorrect. I'm using the the version 5.3.4-rc3 from Lua.org compiled by myself on a Mac OS 10.11.2.

```
function fact(n)
  if n == 0 then return 1 end
  if n < 0 then return 0 end

  return n * fact(n-1)
end

--25! = 15511210043330985984000000 . From http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25!
local n = 15511210043330985984000000
assert(n == 15511210043330985984000000)
print(n)
assert(fact(4) == 24)
assert(fact(10) == 3628800)
print(fact(25))
assert(fact(25) == 15511210043330985984000000) --The problem!
```

I can see the the problem on the code "print(fact(25))" and it is checked by the assertion on the last line. I tested the code with the Lua versions 5.2.4, 5.3.3 and 5.3.4-rc3 and I had the same problem. On the version 5.3.2 the problem doesn't happen but there is another problem related to the number/string conversion on this version. On this version I also tested the values 25!, 35!, 100! without any problem.

Comment: Could you report this issue on the Lua mailing list, since it might be a regression? lua-l@lists.lua.org is the address.

Comment: 25! > 2^64, so your integers gets wraparound-ed.  Lua can not store exact 25! as a number value.

Comment: BTW, 25! ends by 6 zeroes.  Your asserted value has 8.

Comment: The links shows me the output **15511210043330985984000000** for 25!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You're right. The limitation is related to the number type with int subtype in Lua 5.3. On the Lua 5.2 the default was use float for all numbers. The only workaround that I see for this situation is change the subtype of the function for float (the default on Lua 5.3 is double, so around 10^308 limit). The problem is with it I will add imprecision for high values because the float types. I checked it with 35! and the I already see differences. :S Any tip for implement a factorial func for big int in Lua ?

Comment: @chentz - [fact(25)](http://pastebin.com/wUSFSBvH)

Comment: You could just make an http request and rip the number from whatever site you're using to doubecheck

Comment: If you want arbitrary precision arithmetic in Lua, see one of my libraries at http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html, for instance lbc.